# How do I extract only certain parts of ffmpeg's standard output as it processes a file?

Tags: sed, grep, terminal, osx, ffmpeg

I want to enter a command that only shows these two lines of ffmpeg's output and I want to see it **as it processes a file:**

```bsh
from 'input_file.mkv':
frame=172534 fps=4622 q=-1.0 Lsize= 8319963kB time=01:59:56.17 bitrate=9471.3kbits/s speed= 193x
```

This command gives the output I want but frame, fps, etc. only displays after the process has completed.

```bsh
ffmpeg -i input_file.mkv output.mp4 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -E -o '(from .*)|((frame=).*)'
```

How can I display the info I want (and only that info) while it's processing?

#### Background

That's as far as I've gotten by digging online. I don't see any ffmpeg options to filter out as much as I want and the other questions I'm seeing don't seem to fit what I'm looking for. (Most of what I'm seeing are questions about extracting info from a video file or controlling output in a python script that does other things)

Comment: some flavors of `grep` have a `--line-buffered` option among other ways of fiddling with that

Comment: See -progress option.